# Error With Counting Amount of Unfollowers Numbers In This Python Code

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have made this code for unfollowing the unfollowers (non-followers) on instagram but seems the count of that script is appearing wrong.
Ex: There are almost 1000 unfollowers (non-followers) but the script shows on 210 or some random numbers.

```
from InstagramAPI import  InstagramAPI
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime


USERNAME = ''  # put your username between the quotes
PASSWORD = ''  # put your password between the quotes
SUCESSIVE_UNFOLLOWS_BETWEEN = 30 # enter time in seconds for time between two unfollows
UNFOLLOW_BATCH = 100  # enter how much unfollow in one batch
TIME_BETWEEN_BATCHES = 3600 # enter time in seconds for time difference between two unfollows


def get_to_unfollow_list(object):
    following_list = []
    for user in object.getSelfUsersFollowing()['users']:
        following_list.append(user['pk'])

    follower_list = []
    for user in object.getSelfUserFollowers()['users']:
        follower_list.append(user['pk'])

    not_following_me = list(set(following_list) - set(follower_list))
    return not_following_me


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = InstagramAPI(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    inst.login()
    first= True
    firstBatch = True
    while True:
        if not first:
            sleep(86400)
        else:
            first = True
        to_unfollow_list = get_to_unfollow_list(inst)
        while len(to_unfollow_list) > 0:
            if firstBatch:
                firstBatch = False
            else:
                pass
            sleep(TIME_BETWEEN_BATCHES)
            for no, id in enumerate(to_unfollow_list[0:UNFOLLOW_BATCH]):
                name = inst.getUsernameInfo(id)
                sleep(SUCESSIVE_UNFOLLOWS_BETWEEN - 5)
                try:
                    inst.unfollow(id)['user']['username']
                except:
                    pass
                print("Unfollowed #" + str(no + 1) + " " + name)
                sleep(5)
            print("Completed Unfollowing " + str(UNFOLLOW_BATCH) + " unfollowers in " + str(TIME_BETWEEN_BATCHES) + " seconds.")
            try:
                del to_unfollow_list[:UNFOLLOW_BATCH]
            except:
                pass
        print("Completed Unfollowing " + str(len(to_unfollow_list)) + " unfollowers in 1 Hour/Minutes.")
        print("Todays task is completed! Unfollowed " + str(len(to_unfollow_list)) + " followers today (" + str(datetime.now().date()) + ")")
```

Please note there is an API files also includes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfq3tlyog1d9f4z/InstagramAPI.pyc?dl=0

Please help me out fix this....

Comment: You may be missing some crucial debugging info in your try except statement. Use it only for the particular error you are trying to catch.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for some help with modification.